# Webservices Android soap

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

How can I do to consume a WebService? this is my code:

```
WebServiceParams ws = new WebServiceParams(context);

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(ws.getWSNameSpace(), ws.getWSHelloMethod());

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapSerializationEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapSerializationEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    request.addProperty("name", "Charly");

    try {
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportSE = new HttpTransportSE(ws.getWSUrl());
        httpTransportSE.debug = true;

        httpTransportSE.call(ws.getWSNameSpace() + ws.getWSLoginMethod(), soapSerializationEnvelope);

        String xmlResult = soapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse().toString();

        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e;
    }
```

And I get soapFault faultcode soapClient faultstring Unmarshalling Error unexpected element uri:"", local:"name" expected elements are <{}request>

The principal part of the webservice is:

```
<request>
      <name>?</name>
</request>
```

how can I write the request tag and inside the name to send it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're using a library. 
I was able to achieve this using [Ksoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/).

Here you have an example. Hope it helps.

```
public static int getTotalRows(){
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Variables.WEBSERVICE_NAMESPACE,    Variables.METHOD_GETDEALS_TOTAL);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new     SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    env.dotNet = true;
    env.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new      HttpTransportSE(Variables.WEBSERVICE_URL);
    int totalRows = 0;

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.call(Variables.SOAP_ACTION_GETDEALS_TOTALROWS, env);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)env.getResponse();
        totalRows = Integer.valueOf(response.toString());
        Log.i(Variables.TAG, response.toString());
        return totalRows;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return totalRows;
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return totalRows;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return totalRows;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return totalRows;
    }
}
```

Comment: The real question here is How can I send a POJO through webservice?

Comment: You can try to serialize the pojo to JSON using Gson.